# Add 'Delete my account' link in Customer Navigation Menu

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, delete

Is there a way to place a link (ie called `Delete my account` next to the `Log out` link in the Customer Navigation Account Dashboard?

I know there are paid extensions available for that but I'd like to know if it's possible by means of a simple `module` or via the `local.xml`?

Comment: have you got solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml**

For the **Customer account navigation** :

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink">
            <name>delete_my_account</name>
            <path>module/controller</path> //path to your controller function for deleting account
            <label>Delete my account</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

**EDIT:**

The function in your **controller**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId‌​();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
    $customer->delete(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Maybe a little bit dummy, but is there a way to find out that path to the controller function for deleting the customer account? Not really an expert in this matter.

Comment: Would you please add the controller code to answer.

Comment: Please, look my update

Comment: Please, accept the answer if it has been helpful

Comment: Hello guys, this method seems to be quick and simple but still don't know what about controller. As there is in controller indexAction already, what to do with the code ? Where should I add this code to ? app/code/core/Mage/account/controllers/accountController.php ?